# How to autoplay youtube video (without user interaction) in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

I am trying to autoplay video of youtube using YTplayer and load the Youtube video using VideoID,
I had also tried using loadHTMLString in Webview.
is iOS not allow to autoplay youtube ?

here is my code: 1) using YTplayer

```
let fullNameArr = video_url!.componentsSeparatedByString("=")
let video: String = fullNameArr[1]
enYTplayer.webView?.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
 YTplayer.webView?.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
 YTplayer.loadWithVideoId(video)  
 YTplayer.playVideo()
```

2)using webView (iframe)

```
let vidurl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/LG-_Dz6nseQ"
yutub_webview.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(yutub_webview.frame.size.width)\" hight=\"\(yutub_webview.frame.size.height)\" src=\"\(vidurl)?playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen & autoplay=1 &showinfo=0 &controls=0 autohide=1></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
```

3) using HTML

```
let youTubeVideoHTML :NSString = "<html><head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style></head> <body> <div id=\"player\"></div> <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api'; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); var player; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('player', { width:'200', height:'204', videoId:'8LVN7WVgx0c', events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady } }); } function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } </script> </body> </html>";
    yutub_webview.loadHTMLString(youTubeVideoHTML as String,baseURL:nil)
```

and also tried out this one:

```
yutub_webview.loadHTMLString("<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='300' height='200' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/LG-_Dz6nseQ? enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></body></html>",baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
```

but still default play button is there and video not autoplay. 
can any one tell me what i am doing wrong with these?

Comment: are you using official youtube-ios-player-helper in the first process?

Comment: using YTplayer pod i installed pod in my project

Comment: I have recently used this. Works great. Follow the documentation and I hope it should be ok. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Answer (score 3):

after a too much surfing I found the solution :

just add the delegate of YTPlayerViewDelegate

and use its method -

```
func playerViewDidBecomeReady(playerView: YTPlayerView) {
    YTplayer.playVideo()
}
```